# Error : Undefined variable when passing parameter to method in Kohana Controller?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

```
public function get_entity_keyNumber($entity)
    {
        $this->session = Session::instance();   
        (int)$lastNumber = 0;
        $user_data= array_keys($this->session->as_array());
        $user_experience = array_filter($user_data,function($value){return strstr($value, $entity);});
        if(!empty($user_experience))
        {
            $lastElement = end($user_experience);
            (int)$lastNumber = substr($lastElement,-1);
            $lastNumber++;
        }
        return $lastNumber;
    }
```

this function is doing that it return me last character of last key in $user_data and Iam incrementing to it by casting it to Integer.

$user_data = array("experience0") like if i use this function:

```
 (int)$lastNumber = get_entity_keyNumber("experience");
```

It will return me 1 and i will add another array to a session with name experience1 then experience2,experince3 so it cannot overwirte the keys in session

when iam using this function why is this throwing error:
Call to undefined function get_entity_keyNumber() or sometimes $entity variable undefined 
Iam new to php and as well as to kohana

when using inline it works perfectly.

Comment: `get_entity_keyNumber` seems to be a **method** , not a global **function** .

Comment: I misspelled yeah its a method but when i try to use it says that like u said $this->get_entity_keyNumber("experience") its throwing a error that entity variable is not defined and this method is defined in same class where I am using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$instance->get_entity_keyNumber("experience");
```

`$instance` means an instance of the class that the method `get_entity_keyNumber` belongs to.

In the class definition field, it'll be `$this`.

I'm sorry for not knowing about *kohana*.

Comment: I misspelled yeah its a method but when i try to use it says that like u said $this->get_entity_keyNumber("experience") its throwing a error that entity variable is not defined and this method is defined in same class where I am using it.

Answer (score 0):

I used private attribute in class with same name  and assigned value of method parameter to it and used that class attribute using $this to filter array values, My OOP is weak :)

```
private $entity;
public function get_entity_keyNumber($entity)
{
    $this->$entity =$entity;
    $this->session = Session::instance();   
    (int)$lastNumber = 0;
    $user_data= array_keys($this->session->as_array());
    $user_experience = array_filter($user_data,function($value){return strstr($value, $this->entity);});
    if(!empty($user_experience))
    {
        $lastElement = end($user_experience);
        (int)$lastNumber = substr($lastElement,-1);
        $lastNumber++;
    }
    return $lastNumber;
}
```